# $\left \langle f,g \right \rangle$ defines an inner real product in $\mathcal{C}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, trigonometry, solution-verification, inner-products

Consider $\mathcal{C}[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ the vectorial $\mathbb{R}$ space of continuous real functions in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. For $f,g \in \mathcal{C}[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ define

$$\left \langle f,g \right \rangle=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(t)f(t)g(t)dt.$$

Prove $\left \langle f,g \right \rangle$ defines an inner real product in $\mathcal{C}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

**Attempt:**

$\bullet$ Linearity follows from the linearity of the integral.

$\bullet$ Conjugate symmetry follows from
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)f(t)g(t)dt=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)g(t)f(t)dt.$$

$\bullet$ If $0 \neq f \in \mathcal{C}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, then
$$\left \langle f|f \right \rangle=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(t)f^{2}(t)dt>0$$
because of the continuity of $f$, $f^{2}>0$, the continuity of $\cos$ and $\cos >0$ in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Since $\left \langle 0,0 \right \rangle=0$ holds, positive definiteness follows from

$\bullet$ Since $f\in \mathcal{C}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $f^{2} \geq 0$. Since $\cos >0$ in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\left \langle f,f \right \rangle=0\implies f=0$.

$\bullet$ If $f \in \mathcal{C}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $f^{2} \geq 0$. Since $\cos>0$ in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\left \langle f,f \right \rangle\geq 0,\forall f \in \mathcal{C}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ follows.

$\therefore$ $\left \langle f,g \right \rangle$ defines an inner real product in $\mathcal{C}[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: You want bilinearity, rather than linearity, technically.

Comment: Also, $f^2\geq 0.$ is all you know, and that $f^2(x)>0$ for some $x.$ It is wrong to describe this as $f^2>0.$

Comment: But if $f\neq 0$, isn't $f^{2}>0$? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Does bilinearity follows from the properties of the integral anyways?

Comment: No, $f$ can be zero in part of the interval. $f\neq 0$ means some $f(x_0)\neq 0,$ not all $f(x)\neq 0.$ Your argument for "linearity" is only wrong in terminology. It is fine for bilinearity.

Comment: @Shambhala It is a minor problem, $f^2>0$ would be read as $f^2(x)>0$ for *all* $x$ rather than for at least some $x$. But I’m sure you meant the latter (else you should not need continuity).

Comment: So should I change the redaction to $f^{2}(x)>0,\forall x$? @Lazy

Comment: No, you do not get this property. You get $f^2(x)>0$ at least on a small neighborhood, which is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is mostly correct. Generally you only need $\cos>0$, so you can do this with any function $w$ with $w>0$ and $w$ sufficiently nice to be integrable. This can then be seen as weighted variation of the standard ip with weight function $w$.